# How to prevent continuous click Enter key multiple times with Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to prevent continuous press "Enter" key multiple times in TextBox with Google Apps Script, but I don't know how to do.
Thanks for help!

The following coding is part of my Google Site Application, when I press "Enter" key, it will add a TextBox's (which named "voter") value into a ListBox (which named "listGmailUser") and another TextBox (which named "voterSelect"). But if I continuous press "Enter" key multiple times in the "voter" TextBox, it will add the repetitive "voter" TextBox's value into the "listGmailUser" ListBox. But this is not what I want, so I hope somebody could help me solve this problem.  Thanks!

```
if (e.parameter.keyCode==13 && listBoxCount > 0 && e.parameter.voter != "") {
app.getElementById('listGmailUser').clear().setVisible(false); 
app.getElementById('voter').setValue('');

if (e.parameter.voterSelect == "") 
{
  app.getElementById('voterSelect').setText(firstItem.replace(/(\s*$)/g, ""));
  app.getElementById('listSelectVoter').addItem(firstItem);
}
else
{
  var value = e.parameter.voterSelect;
  var arrVoter = value.split(",");
  var index = arrVoter.indexOf(firstItem);
  Logger.log("value:" + value + ";" + "index:" + index + "firstItem:" + firstItem);
  if (index == -1) {
    app.getElementById('voterSelect').setText(e.parameter.voterSelect + ',' + firstItem.replace(/(\s*$)/g, ""));
    app.getElementById('listSelectVoter').addItem(firstItem);
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: "continuous click Enter key multiple times" .... what does this mean ? sorry but I find it really unclear. please describe your situation clearly.

Comment: Are you using UiApp or HtmlServer? Please post a MINIMAL code that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @HenriqueAbreu I use UiApp.

Answer (score 0):

In this case of `UiApp` and "enter" key, the only solution (I know) is to use [Lock Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/).

If the events you needed to prevent were clicks or if you were using `HtmlService` there would be better solutions than locking. But not in this case.

I'd do it like this in your code:

```
if (e.parameter.keyCode==13 && listBoxCount > 0 && e.parameter.voter != "") {
  var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
  if( !lock.tryLock(50) ) return;
  //...
```

Comment: I have tried but it still couldn't prevent continuous press "Enter" key multiple times.

Comment: Weird... maybe my understanding of your question is wrong. Do you want to disallow this event to happen completely after it happens the first time?

Comment: Yes, maybe user will continuous press "Enter" key multiple times in a very short time. In this way my coding will add the same voter name from TextBox into the ListBox many times, so there are repeat voter names in the ListBox. I want to disallow this event, if user press the "Enter" key first time, before my coding add the voter into ListBox, he couldn't press "Enter" key second time. Or he could press, but if the interval time is so short, prevent add the voter into ListBox. So thart there will no repeat voter name in the ListBox. Thanks!

Comment: But locking does work. But it seems you'll also need to keep your list of voters somewhere server-side (e.g. ScriptDb), so you can check it without needing to rely on client-side state of the list.